# link Azure AD users with Gsuite

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, google-gsuite

Currently we have all users with their email in Gsuite. And we have these same users with Azure AD to login and use Devops, Azure and Apps

How can I join these users to only use a single account? This can be done with Federation Services? Or some other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways you can integrate the accounts:

1. [SSO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/google-apps-tutorial)
2. [User Provisioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/g-suite-provisioning-tutorial)

When you configure **SSO** in Azure AD for G Suite you get the following benefits:

- Controlling access to G Suite from Azure AD
- Allowing users to be automatically signed-in to G Suite with their Azure AD Account (and vice versa)
- Managing accounts in one central location – Azure AD

**Provisioning** allows you to:

- Create users in G Suite
- Remove users in G Suite when they do not require access anymore
- Keep user attributes synchronized between Azure AD and G Suite
- Provision groups and group memberships in G Suite

You can establish a link relationship between your Azure AD users and the related users in G Suite and map users by UPN or email address.

Recommended steps:

1. Go to the Google Cloud (G Suite) Connector application integration page and [Configure Azure AD SSO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/google-apps-tutorial).
2. [Configure Google Cloud (G Suite) Connector SSO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/google-apps-tutorial#configure-google-cloud-g-suite-connector-sso) - to configure the single sign-on settings on application side.